# Integral of electric field $E$ is $0$ implies that the field is $0$?

Tags: physics, electromagnetism

If we consider $\vec{E}$ the electric field in $R^n$ and we have : 
$$\int_{R}^{\infty}\vec{E}(\vec{r})d\vec{r}=0$$
where $R$ is in $R^n$ and $\vec{r}$ is in $R^n$
$$\vec{E}(\vec{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0 \mid \vec{r}\mid^2}\vec{e_r}$$

Then do we have that $\vec{E}=0$ everywhere is we make the assumption that $E(\vec{r})=E(r)$ ? 
Thanks

Comment: You should clarify the meaning of the written equation in view of the fact that both $E$ and $r$ are vectors.

Comment: I agree @user, without clarifying what you mean by $r$ and $E$ which are normally vectors, but could be some component or magnitude, it is difficult if not impossible to answer your question. (eg if $E$ is the magnitude then the plausible answers is different than if $E$ is say the radial component or vector quantity.)

Comment: If in the second equation $\vec{e_r}$ means unit vector directed to/from coordinate center, the given integral is never $0$ but has a value $-\frac1{4\pi\epsilon_0R}$. If you just want to assume that the field has spherical symmetry, then the integral can be $0$ also for non-zero field. Nothing changes comparing with one-dimensional case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "no". The integral can be $0$ also for non-zero field. For example consider two concentric charged spheres $R_1<R_2$  with 
$$\frac{Q_1}{R_1}=-\frac{Q_2}{R_2}.$$

Then for $R<R_1$ the integral in question is $0$ but the field outside the inner sphere is certainly not.

Answer (score 0):

The work required to bring a charge $Q$ from infinitely far away and place it at a point $\vec{R}$ is

$$W=Q(V(\vec{R})-V(\infty)$$

If we suppose the electric field is spherically symmetric (which, presumably,you are doing), then this is just

$$W=Q(V(R)-V(\infty))$$

The integral that you have is

$$\int_R^\infty E(r)dr=V(R)-V(\infty)$$

just based on the definition of the electric field (in the spherical symmetric case)

$$E(r)=-\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}r}V(r)$$

Thus in your case, $W=0$ to bring a charge from $r=\infty$ to $r=R$. Because we had to make the assumption that the electric field was spherically symmetric, it follows that for $W$ to be zero, there must be no charges in the space because if it is spherically symmetric, we can write the field as having some net charge at the origin. If $W=0$, then this net charge at the origin must be zero, and thus $E(r)=0~\forall~r$.

Please note I say "spherical" but this works for all $n$.